# Расстояние между всеми точками массива

Tags: c++

Проинициализировать два массива, которые задают n точек координатами (X, Y) в двумерном пространстве.Описать функцию, которая найдет расстояния между всеми точками и выведет их на экран в виде таблицы.

Считает расстояние только между двумя точками. Что не так в коде?

```
float alldist(int *x, int *y);
int main()
{ 
    int *x=new int [5] {1, 4, 6, 2, 1}; 
    int *y=new int [5] {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
    cout << "Расстояние между всеми точками:" << alldist(x, y) << endl;
}

float alldist(int *x, int *y) 
{
    float d;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)
        {
            d = sqrt(pow((x[i+1] - x[i]), 2) + pow((y[j+1] - y[j]), 2));
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Одно* расстояние между *всеми* точками? "Семь красных линий. Все строго перпендикулярны."

Comment: В коде написано - вернуть первое же расстояние. Всё, приехали. Если поясните, что означает "расстояни**е** между всеми точками", то можно дальше думать.

Comment: Мне гораздо больше нравится `x[i]` и `y[j]`. Это между чем расстояние?

Comment: не судите строго, я новичок, подскажите как исправить

Comment: исправлено условие

Comment: ОК. Таблица - значит, понадобится (двумерный) массив. Возможностями c++  пользоваться будете? Если да, то вектор векторов можно возвращать из функции. А может, и не надо ничего возвращать - функция их просто напечатает по ходу вычислений.

Comment: можете подсказать, как написать код?

Comment: у вас во втором цикле увеличивается счётчик `i` вместо `j`. Так и задумывалось ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то [вроде такого](https://ideone.com/HheslK):

```
void alldist(int *x, int *y, int n) 
{
    float d;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            d = sqrt(pow((x[j] - x[i]), 2) + pow((y[j] - y[i]), 2));
            cout <<"dist "<< i << ":" << j << " " << d << " ";
        }
            cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: открывается консоль, но ничего не выводит

Comment: Я ссылку добавил

Comment: все работает.  а если маскимальное расстояние нужно вывести,  то это можно сделать в этом же коде?

Comment: каждый раз после вычисления нужно сравнивать результат с текущим максимумом